# PHP - How to concatenation 2 php var for create a new php var?

Tags: php

PHP - How to concatenation 2 php var for create a new php var?

I want to concatenation `$test` with `$i` for create a new php var.

like this but not work, how can i do ?

```
<?PHP
$i = "5";
$test_$i = "WELCOME";
echo $test_5;
?>
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Most likely there is a much better solution. Could you explain your usecase please?

Comment: @PeeHaa For learning purposes? PHP Lesson 1 teaches this thing! `:P`

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) :

```
<?php
    $i = "5";
    ${'test_' . $i} = "WELCOME";
    echo $test_5; // echoes "WELCOME"
?>
```